# Users.threads.list not returning all pages/threads

Tags: gmail-api

Calling Users.threads.list on a label with 162 threads with maxResults=50 so there should be 4 pages. Third page doesn't have a nextPageToken (even when specifically requested in fields) so I can't get the last page. Also, the third page only returns 46 threads. Tried includeSpamTrash=true didn't fix it. Verified results through the in-page API tester at https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list.

Comment: Where do you get the "162 threads" number?  From web UI or somewhere else?  When you fetch all ~146 threads in the results are there 162 messages total?

Comment: Yes web UI and I have separately synced all emails and when I count threads in the label from my copy of the data I get 162. Also User.labels.get shows 162 {
 "id": "Label_50",
 "name": "Unimportant/Calendar",
 "messageListVisibility": "show",
 "labelListVisibility": "labelShow",
 "type": "user",
 "messagesTotal": 280,
 "messagesUnread": 262,
 "threadsTotal": 162,
 "threadsUnread": 148
}

Comment: Can you post your code around this specifically the request(s) being made?  Returning only 3 pages with the last page only having 46 results == 146 total and that's very close to threadsUnread...

Comment: Can you still reproduce this?